# testthat dividing by zero

Tags: r, exception, testthat

I'm wondering how to use the `testthat` package to check division by zero. By default, `R` returns `Inf` when trying to divide by zero. I, on the other hand, want to check if the user has somehow handled dividing by 0 and replaced it with some other result, such as some text like ("Don't divide by 0!").

The problem is this: user can replace the result with any text, not necessarily the one I use in the formula for testing.
So **how to check if the user has inserted anything other than the default `Inf`?**

sample user view:

```
divide <- function(x, y) {
  if(y!=0) x/y 
  else
    "Do not divide by zero"
}
```

and test (so far):

```
test_that("divide by zero", {
  expect_equivalent(divide(2, 0),"Do not divide by 0")
})
```

The test will obviously fail due to different character strings.

Comment: We probably need a bit more context here. What exactly does the user have control over, and what do you control? Are you able to force the `divide` function to emit a warning, or throw an error? For example, your function could be `divide <- function(x,y) { if(y == 0) stop('Do not divide by zero'); x/y}` and you could use `expect_error('Do not divide by zero')` in `test_that`.

Comment: @Allan Cameron The user is tasked with writing a divide function, and I want to see if it has handled divide-by-zero in some way, that's it. He can do it however he likes, and that's the problem. Your solution will show an error if the user writes `0` instead of `zero`, which is why I want to check if the divide-by-zero test returns anything other than the default `Inf`. Literally `expect_equivalent(divide(2, 0),Anything but Inf)`.

Comment: What about `expect_false(is.infinite(divide(2, 0)))`?

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you! Feel free to write an answer if you like :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user is writing a function that needs to divide but must handle dividing by zero in some way (other than the default of returning `Inf`), we could do:

```r
expect_false(is.infinite(divide(2, 0)))
```